# Airspeed and RPM relationship with different attitudes

Tags: engine

How can I figure out what airspeed goes with what rpm? I cannot find it in the POH.
I read that for cruising attitude on a Cessna 152, we should aim for 2200 rpm. My plane is a PA-28-151.
I am asking this because when I go on a flight with my instructor, numbers such as 1500, 2000, and 2400 rpm are used often when either climbing or descending.

Any tips from experience or references is much appreciated.

Comment: I would *highly* recommend an hour or two spent fiddling around.  Even better if you can have a safety pilot, and even better if you have something like a Go Pro type of camera watching the panel.  Get the plane trimmed up straight and level, and leave *everything* the same and reduce RPM by 100.  Then another 100…  Then another…  and record how many FPM your descent increases.  Same thing with speed:  Set 2200 RPM and note the speed.  Then reduce RPM 100 at a time and stay in level flight, recording the speeds.   You’ll start to develop a “sense” of how power, speed and VS are linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fact I assume you know, but for the sake of completeness of this answer it's worth nothing that the relationship between RPM and airspeed is not unique - it will depend, among other things on aircraft configuration (e.g. flaps), power setting, the use of carburetor heat, and more. The obvious example being slow flight in a "dirty" configuration may require the same RPM to maintain level flight as might be common when in cruise.

With that out of the way, to better develop a set of RPM targets which you can use for common phases of flight such as climb, cruise, and descent, you were right to look at the POH. If the POH for your PA-28-151 is anything like the one for the PA-28-161 I have with me, RPM setting are not prescribed for everything, but here are some points I'd start with - just note to find the correct values for your aircraft.

- The static RPM at full throttle, e.g. between 2330 - 2430 RPM. This is not a number you should see anywhere except verifying before releasing the brakes during a short short field takeoff, but provides a helpful bound.
- I don't see stated anywhere in the normal procedures that takeoff/climb power is anything other than full, so full power should be used until cruise. Given the airspeeds for various types of takeoffs/climbs are prescribed, you'll be able to use full power, fly the prescribed airspeeds, note what RPM you see during these phases (along with other conditions). This exercise would probably be of minimal value, except to note if you observe changes in the RPM from what you determine to be expected values.
- I expect in your POH you should have a chart like the below that will allow you from temperature, pressure altitude, and power output what the corresponding RPM will be.

[image]

So during cruise, you can decide what power setting is appropriate. Your instructor certainly may suggest full power during your training simply in the interest of time, you can decide for longer flights if you can accept a longer flight time at a lower power setting to save on fuel. But nevertheless, there is quite a range of acceptable cruise power settings.

I also notice the following note in the PA-28-161 POH which if you can find the manual for your engine, may provide some additional information.

> Refer to the appropriate Avco Lycoming Operator's Manual when selecting the cruise power setting

- The normal descent procedure says 2500 rpm, 126 KIAS. While that is a helpful configuration to reference, it's certainly not the only acceptable power setting for a descent. Additionally, it'll be helpful to have power settings for instrument approaches, when in the traffic pattern, and when pulling the power abeam the numbers, as a few examples. For these, there aren't any "correct" power settings, but rather a range that may be reasonable.

So I do suggest taking the values from the POH where they exist, and then finding some reference values online from reputable schools and/or spend a few moments during your next flight with your instructor to determine and dial in values that work well for these common phases of flight. Note these down and follow them so you can approach each phase of flight consistently and avoid confusion if your instructor is giving you slightly different power settings each time and you don't understand why.  For example (*note: these are not necessarily correct values for your aircraft*) something like the following:

- Takeoff/climb: full power

  - regardless of Vx, Vy, or enroute climb, etc.
- Cruise: 2400 - 2500 RPM

  - See cruise chart for corresponding airspeed
- Descent: 2100 RPM

  - Descending at cruise airspeed, or use the POH descent values above
- Instrument approach: 1800 RPM

  - ~90 KIAS
- Traffic pattern: 2100 RPM

  - ~100 KIAS
- Abeam numbers: 1500 RPM

  - Pitch for 85 KIAS
- Slow flight: 1800 RPM

  - 65 KIAS

So, while this answer doesn't strictly provide the values you are looking for, hopefully it provides some direction for climb and cruise, and points you in the right direction for some of the other phases of flight.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for your inputs.